# Share Photo on Facebook using Facebook 4.0 without native app installed

Tags: android, facebook, image, sharing

I'm using Facebook 4.0 to share photos through my app but I'm unable to share photos from my phone. I can share an image from the internet by providing it's url but it doesn't work for an image from the phone. The code I'm using for sharing is below.

```
public void sharePhoto(Uri contentUri, String contentTitle, Bitmap image, String contentDescription){
    ShareDialog facebookDialog = new ShareDialog(getActivity());

    ShareLinkContent.Builder content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder();
    content.setContentUrl(contentUri);
    content.setContentTitle(contentTitle);
    content.setImageUrl(getImageUri(getActivity(), image));
    content.setContentDescription(contentDescription);

    ShareLinkContent shareContent = content.build();

    facebookDialog.show(shareContent);

}

public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

I know I can share a bitmap from the phone using the following

```
public void shareImage(Bitmap image){
    ShareDialog facebookDialog = new ShareDialog(getActivity());
    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(image).build();
    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder().addPhoto(photo).build();
    facebookDialog.show(content);

}
```

However this code requires that the native facebook app be installed on the phone. Is there some way to share a bitmap without having the native app installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the native app is not installed, the only other way to share a bitmap is to get `publish_actions` permission from the user, and do a POST to me/photos (you can use the ShareApi class to do the actual post for you, but you still need to ask for the permission from the user). Unfortunately, the web-based dialogs do not support uploading binary data.

Comment: i have to share multiple images on Facebook if app is installed it works fine but if app is not installed then sharedialog is not uploading the bitmap,same like above scenario but i am passing permissions also but after that its not working

Comment: It doesn't matter what permissions you have, the web share dialog does not support photo uploads. You have to do it via the API.

Comment: @MingLi Can you share small example for it.

Answer (score -1):

Sharing multiple images with fb sdk and without native facebook installed. First login and then use below function.

```
private void postPhoto() {

ArrayList<SharePhoto> photos = new ArrayList<>();

    SharePhoto sharePhoto1 = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(image1).build();

    SharePhoto sharePhoto = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(image).build();

    photos.add(sharePhoto);
    photos.add(sharePhoto1);

    SharePhotoContent sharePhotoContent =
            new SharePhotoContent.Builder().setPhotos(photos).build();
    ShareApi.share(sharePhotoContent, shareCallback);
}
```